# how can I directly create a meeting in flutter jitsi meet after changing the server url without authentification?

Tags: flutter, jitsi-meet

I'm using jitsi meet package for a video conferencing app, every thing is working perfectly when create a meeting with the default serverURL. as in the code :

[image]

the problem accur when deleting the // so my serverURL will be actif.so i got this:

[image]

any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond a solution.
you just have to add the ..token parameter. see the documentation https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet#jitsimeetingoptions.

Comment: hello can i ask hot did you change the default serverurl i have created my own server and enabled feature flag for changing serverurl but it still uses the default ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829424/how-to-change-flutter-jitsi-meet-serverurl

Comment: I think you have a problem with your serveur, mine works normally by only changing the server url value.

Comment: Do you know how can i change the interface for the meeting room